# Search for a certain element in a List and delete it

Tags: string, list, kotlin

I have a `List<String>` in kotlin which contains the following elements

```
"Bank", "of", "Luxemburg", "Orange", "County"
```

How do I search the `List` if it contains `"of"`?

How can I get the `position` of `"of"` and then delete it from the list?

Comment: use flatmap, ignore elements "of" in closure

Comment: If you MUST change the list go with other answers, otherwise @AlexandrKolesnik answer above is the way to go

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik Thanks for the comment. I'll definitely look into using flatmaps. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First be sure that your list is a mutable list:

```
val list = mutableListOf("bank", "of" , "Luxemburg", "Orange", "country")
```

Or if you already have a list:

```
val newList = list.toMutableList()
```

then do this:

```
list.remove("bank")
```

output:

```
[of, Luxemburg, Orange, country]
```

If you have more copy value in same list do it:

```
 list.removeAll(listOf("Luxemburg"))
```

output:

```
[bank, of, Luxemburg, Orange, country, Luxemburg]
[bank, of, Orange, country]
```

Comment: If you need to transform the mutable list to a list because you use List<String> in some function or class, don't be afraid, you can always create a list from a mutable list, just by passing the entire mutable list in the constructor

Comment: here more information if you are interested in using collections:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections-overview.html

Comment: This will only remove the first occurrence of `"of"`... If that's enough, then *nice answer* ;-)

Comment: it doesn't remove the first element, try it with Luxemburg.
Ah ok you mean all elements.
I edit, now also copy are removed.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to remove the first `"of"` found in the list, then `remove` will be sufficient. If you want to remove every occurrence of `"of"`, then use `removeIf` or maybe even `removeAll`:

```
fun main() {
    val l: MutableList<String>
                = mutableListOf("Bank", "of", "Luxemburg", "of", "Orange", "of", "County")
    val m: MutableList<String>
                = mutableListOf("Bank", "of", "Luxemburg", "of", "Orange", "of", "County")
    println(l)
    // remove first "of" found
    l.remove("of")
    println(l)
    // remove every element that equals "of"
    l.removeIf { it == "of" }
    println(l)

    println("————————————————————————————————")
    // use removeAll
    println(m)
    m.removeAll { it == "of" }
    println(m)
}
```

The output is

```
[Bank, of, Luxemburg, of, Orange, of, County]
[Bank, Luxemburg, of, Orange, of, County]
[Bank, Luxemburg, Orange, County]
————————————————————————————————
[Bank, of, Luxemburg, of, Orange, of, County]
[Bank, Luxemburg, Orange, County]
```

Comment: There is a `removeAll(predicate)` that does the same thing as `removeIf(filter)` but is not JDK-only.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the elements back without "of" you can filter them

```
val list = listOf("bank", "of" , "Luxemburg", "Orange", "country")
val result = list.filter { it != "of" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work:
`list.indexOf("of").also { if (it != -1) list.removeAt(index) }`